# WordPress not able to login in WordPress admin and getting error : WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'action' in 'field list']

Tags: wordpress

when i do login in `WordPress` admin i am getting error  : `WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'action' in 'field list']`, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ? I tried many ways to debugging it but still not able to login, can anyone please help me which steps do i need to take resolve this issue ? any help will be really appreciated, i also renamed the plugin folder still issue persist, is it any issue with database ? on wp-login.php page for this `$user = wp_signon( '', $secure_cookie );` i am getting proper response but somewhere after then getting the issue

Comment: Edit your question and show some codes what you did, none can help with the infos given in question, we cant see guess about columns in your database can we ?

Comment: Rename all the plugins one by one and try to loggin